# Como salvar uma coleção em cascata no nhibernate sem colocar referencia circular?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

Sempre quando tento salvar um objeto com uma coleção de dados mapeado como `HasMany` eu tenho que colocar uma referência circular para que o NHibernate consiga salvar esse objeto em cascata.

Por exemplo tenho o seguinte mapeamento da classe pai.

```
public class ClasseMap : ClassMap<Classe>
{
    public ClasseMap()
    {
      Table("tClasse");

      HasMany<Metodo>(t => t.Metodos)
     .KeyColumn("IdClasse")
     .Inverse()
     .Cascade
     .SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

E na classe filha

```
public class MetodoMap : ClassMap<Metodo>
{
    public MetodoMap()
    {
      Table("tMetodo");

      References(t => t.Classe)
            .Column("IdClasse")
            .ForeignKey("FK_Metodo_IdClasse");
    }
}
```

Quando vou salvar os dados do meu objeto `Classe` faço o seguinte:

```
public class RepositorioClasse
{
    protected readonly ISession SessaoAtual;

    public RepositorioClasse(ISession sessaoAtual)
    {
        SessaoAtual = sessaoAtual;
    }

    public SalvaEntidades() {
        var classe = new Classe();
        var metodo = new Metodo(){
                           Nome= "ToString",
                           TipoRetorno="String",
                           Classe= classe
                          };    

        classe.Nome = "String";
        classe.Metodos.Add(metodo);

        SessaoAtual.SaveUpdate(classe);
   }
}
```

Se eu somente colocar uma coleção de `Metodos` em `Classe` e retirar a referência de `Classe` em `Metodo` o NHibernate não salva e retorna uma exceção dizendo que eu devo ter uma referencia de `Classe` em `Metodo`.

Comment: Olá Marcos. Poderias complementar sua pergunta colocando a mensagem original da exceção que ocorre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observando seu comentário:

> [...] Tendo todas essas informações o NHibernate poderia simplesmente
>   dar um insert na tabela tClasse e depois dar um insert na tabela
>   tMetodo inserindo no campo IdClasse o id da classe que eu acabei de
>   salvar

Isso não irá acontecer neste caso pois na cláusula `HasMany` você definiu a relação como `.Inverse()`. Na prática, o que você está dizendo é que a entidade filha (neste caso, `Metodo`) é que irá se responsabilizar em manter o controle da relação entre os dois (ou seja, o contrário do que você pretende).

Se estiveres com o inglês afiado, sugiro ler este [trechinho da documentação do NHibernate.](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild-bidir)

Resumindo: Tente remover o `Inverse()`. É *possível* que funcione.

Comment: Fiz o teste utilizando o SqLite e deixei o mapeamento sem o Inverse(), num primeiro momento o NHibernate salvou as duas entidades mas não salvou a chave de tClasse na tabela de tMetodo. No entanto adicionei no mapeamento da minha coleção de Metodos um Not.KeyNullable() e funcionou bacana.

Comment: Show! Bom saber :)

Answer (score 0):

Pensando apenas em banco de dados (sem NH), como você faria um SELECT na tabela Métodos para trazer os métodos de uma determinada Classe sem ter o Classe.Id nessa tabela (FK)? Conseguiu ver o problema?

Não faz sentido ter uma coleção de Métodos dentro de Classe sem ter o Id de Classe dentro de Método. É através desse Id que o NH sabe quais Métodos ele tem que buscar para preencher a coleção. Se não tivéssemos esse Id da Classe, o NH teria que buscar TODOS os registros na tabela de Métodos, o que significa que não há uma relação entre as duas entidades.

Comment: Sim, pensando no banco não faz sentido eu não ter uma FK da tabela tClasse na tabela tMetodo, por isso que no mapeamento eu digo pro NHibernate keyColunm("IdClasse") ou seja a minha FK na tabela tMetodo é IdClasse. Então através do mapeamento ele sabe que a FK é IdClasse e sabe que a tabela onde deve salvar o registro filho é tMetodo porque o tipo da minha coleção é Metodo. Tendo todas essas informações o NHibernate poderia simplesmente dar um insert na tabela tClasse e depois dar um insert na tabela tMetodo inserindo no campo IdClasse o id da classe que eu acabei de salvar.

Comment: @Iscoder *"Não faz sentido ter uma coleção de Métodos dentro de Classe sem ter o Id de Classe dentro de Método."*, mas, mas...    **mas ele tem a FK lá sim!** (Coluna `IdClasse`, constraint `FK_Metodo_IdClasse`)